# Angular typeahead shows suggestion on top of results

Tags: angular-ui, angular-ui-typeahead

Im using Angular UI typeahead directive. I have set a custom template for the popup but, it shows a "preview" above my list of results. What is weird is if I try to inspect the infringing element, it disappears! It only shows up when I am typing. [angular ui typeahead showing suggestions on top of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QonOI.png)

You can see on the image below:
I also have set `typeahead-show-hint` to `false`. What else can I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Im sorry, it was Chrome's auto suggestion kicking in. Boy, do i feel dumb.